# What is is being described in this question?

Tags: riddle

You can't eat it raw - but once boiled, you throw it out.

But Olympic athletes would not throw it out.

What is it?

**NOTE**: this is not a word game puzzle. "eat" implies "eat", not "drink".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> A [bay laurel leaf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurus_nobilis)?

You can't eat it raw - but once boiled, you throw it out.

> Bay leaves are used as a seasoning in cooking, often in soups. You boil them to release the flavor, but you throw them out after (they are widely thought to be poisonous)

But Olympic athletes would not throw it out.

> A laurel wreath would be very treasured by an Olympian.

Answer (score 4):

This is likely a terrible guess, but

> Water?

You can't eat it raw - but once boiled, you throw it out.

> I think this was you being rather tricky.  You don't eat water when cooked or when raw because you don't eat it at all.  I am thinking that the second part has to do with boiling water for foods that you then proceed to strain the water out of, such as pasta.  I know when I am cooking spaghetti I throw water out after boiling it!

But Olympic athletes would now throw it out.

> I think this is talking about the water conditions in Brazil for the Rio Games.  As you likely know, boiling water helps make it safe for consumption.  So boiled water would be precious for them.

That's all I got!

Comment: no - Please see the update

Answer (score 3):

> Mussels (Muscles)

You can't eat it raw - but once boiled, you throw it out.

> I assume (I don't like seafood much) that cooking mussels to boiling point ruins the taste.

But Olympic athletes would not throw it out.

> Weightlifters especially would like as many muscles as they can get.   But most athletes need muscles of some sort or other.  Even the non-physical sports require a well-developed brain muscle.

Comment: no - your assumption is 100% wrong. You can definitely boil and eat mussels: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=boiled%20mussles

Comment: Fairly sure the brain isn't a muscle.. if that helps!

Comment: @arth - LOL - That's what happens when I don't exercise my brain enough - I put up badly-researched comments!